# Unequilateral triangular icosahedron

Tags: geometry

I am doing a project and making a triangular icosahedron. I am thinking I might not use equilateral triangles to make it smaller. Is this possible?

Comment: You can also make an icosahedron smaller by using smaller equilateral triangles.

Comment: The comment by @Rahul seems apropos.  Perhaps you mean something specific by "smaller"?  If so, please clarify in your post.

Comment: The traditional icosahedron can be thought of as two pentagonal pyramids stuck onto the pentagonal faces of a pentagonal antiprism. You can certainly make the pentagonal pyramids shorter, and probably the antiprism too - although that would really only make it smaller in one direction.

Comment: Thank you pjs36, this helped. Answering brian tung meant for 1 dimension to be smaller.